# Android Studio DatatypeFactoryImpl not found

Tags: java, android, xml, xerces

I try to generate an XML file with android studio and i get this error:

```
 Caused by: javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeConfigurationException: Provider org.apache.xerces.jaxp.datatype.DatatypeFactoryImpl not found.
```

The problem come from the "JAXBContext" line.
I have a fonction which make XML file its code is

```
        try {

        File file = new File("D:\\Github\\Comedu\\file.xml");
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Resultat.class);
        Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();

        // output pretty printed
        jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

        jaxbMarshaller.marshal(this, file);
        jaxbMarshaller.marshal(this, System.out);

    } catch (JAXBException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

On android studio i add the xerces package to my buildpath, so i don't know how to resolve this.

Answer (score 8):

If you are an Android Developer, as the document said `Note that you must supply your own implementation (such as Xerces); Android does not ship with a default implementation.` https://developer.android.com/reference/javax/xml/datatype/DatatypeFactory.html#newInstance%28%29

So, try adding dependency `xercesImpl`

Maven:

```xml
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/xerces/xercesImpl -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>xerces</groupId>
    <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
    <version>2.12.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Gradle:

```
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/xerces/xercesImpl
compile group: 'xerces', name: 'xercesImpl', version: '2.12.0'
```

Comment: To add 'xerces' in android project use this dependency: implementation("xerces:xercesImpl:2.8.0")
Source: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/xerces/xercesImpl/2.8.0